# How to save path to image in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, angular

I have a table in my db with images, all images are stored on server side folder, so when I am saving an image, in url column I am writing path to its folder

```
INSERT INTO `images` SET `id` = "2", `url`="application/images/goat1.jpg", `album_id` = "1";
```

and then when I get this image to Angular side and trying to use this link as background url, I have an error, because url is undefined.

```
<div *ngFor="let photo of portfolioPreviewPhotos" class="previewPhoto" [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ photo.link +')'"></div>

<div _ngcontent-c2="" class="previewPhoto" style="background-image: url(undefined;);">
```

So, can someone please explain to me how to properly write the path to the image in the database, if I want to store that image in php folder and then get it in Angular

Comment: Shouldn't it be `photo.url`?

Comment: Actually `images.url` based on the minimal amount of code provided. The table is named `images` and the field with the url is named `url`. Really a great deal more information is needed to answer effectively.

Comment: Did you try a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Providing more info would be great, but to store the path it would be the same one when you write it down in url

so if

```
background-image: url("/app/images/someimage.png");
```

then in the database it should be `url` => "/app/images/someimage.png" or if the folder is static then on website

```
background-image: url("/app/images/'url from database'");
```

and in database `ulr` => 'someimage.png'